# incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning 'int' from a function with result type 'void *'

Tags: c

I have the following code that is supposed to create a new array with the number of elements specified in the parameter...

```
void *newArray(int nElements){
    int *array = NULL;
    array = (int *)malloc(nElements * sizeof(int));
    if(array == NULL){
        printf("Insufficient memory space.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //Set all values to 0
    for(int i = 0; i < nElements; i++){
        array[i] = 0;
    }
    return array;
}
```

This function returns a generic pointer to an array of type integer with all its values started at 0. But when I invoke the call to this function...

```
int *array = NULL;
array = (int *)newArray(5);
```

Throws me the following warning:

```
main.c:24:16: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning 'int' from a function with result type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
```

and if I try to print the contents of the array print me two 0.
I'm still getting familiar with the C language and I don't really understand what that warning means and how I can fix it so that the function returns me an array with 5 elements in that case.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag from your question, since you stated that this is about C. C and C++ are different languages, and pointer conversions is one area where they can vary significantly.

Comment: BTW, you can use `calloc()` to allocate the memory and set it to `0` automatically.

Comment: Change return type of `newArray()` to `int *`. I think it is obvious.

Comment: @i486 there is no difference - only you will not have warning when assigning to other pointer types

Comment: @0___________ or maybe the error is from line `return array;` With `int *` funtion type there will be no error. Other solution is `return (void *)array;`. But I don't understand why `void *` type when it is always used for `int *`.

Answer (score 3):

Your function has the return type `void*`. Which will make C try to convert the integer literal `-1` in `return -1` to a `void*`, which an "incompatible conversion". This conversion *is* possible, but it is generally not what you want (as opposed to an `float` to `double` conversion, for example).

To solve this, simply return the null pointer constant `NULL` instead.

Some additional advice:

- Look at the parameter type for [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) and the [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator, it is `size_t`. You may want to have your function accept a `size_t` as well instead. The "size type" is guaranteed to be large enough for any object you could theoretically store, and cannot be negative.
- Setting an entire array of `int` types to zero can be performed by calling [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset). The action of first allocating memory and then setting it all to zeros can be combined using one function call to [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc).
- `malloc` and `calloc` return `NULL` on failure. Therefore you can write:

```
int *array = (int*) malloc(nElements * sizeof(int));
    if(array == NULL){
```

- The return type could also be `int*`, as that type is hardcoded into the function. But perhaps you were gradually writing a `calloc`-like wrapper, which prints an error message in case the allocation failed?

Comment: Indeed the problem was in that return -1. I apreciate it

Comment: do not cast result of malloc

Comment: memset will only  work with `0`. Any other values will have to be manually set in the loop

Comment: @0___________ I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) discussion and consider it disputed. It's not strictly necessary and does add some clutter, but on the other hand, there's also something to be said for having no implicit conversions.

Comment: Another discussion is `sizeof(..)` vs. `sizeof *`, but I'm not going to write an entire C-course here :)

Comment: @that discussion is prehistoric :) Novadays too many people try to compile the C code using C++ compilers. That is the reason to not cast. If it will not compile - tell your compiler to comple as C

Comment: Hah :)  I see C and C++ as separate languages. Do you have a reference that shows that this is relevant problem and the right solution? If there is, I will be convinced to not cast.

Answer (score 1):

```
    return -1;
```

You return `-1` which is integer and your function returns pointer.

The most common way of signaling the caller that something has gone wrong is to return NULL.

```
void *newArray(size_t nElements){
    int *array = NULL;
    array = malloc(nElements * sizeof(*array));
    if(array == NULL){
        printf("Insufficient memory space.\n");
    }
    else
    {
       //Set all values to 0
       for(size_t i = 0; i < nElements; i++){
           array[i] = 0;
    }
    return array;
}
```

As you see you do not have to add a second return. Generally, for code clarity, it is good to avoid many returns in the function.

Some additional remarks:

1. Do not cast the `malloc` return pointers. If your code does not compile it maens that you compile C code using C++ compiler and it is wrong. Most C++ compilers have command line options to set the language (for example `g++ -xc`)
2. Use **objects** not **types** in `sizeof`
3. Use `size_t` for sizes & array indexes.

I do not know why you return `void *` instead of `int *`, but maybe you have some reasons.